# haw to create many2one with xml rpc ODOO v14?

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

i want to create PRODUCT I want to show 'categ_id' How can it be accomplished  'categ_id'  . fields many2one with XML RPC

Comment: Just provide the `categ_id` (ID as integer) in the values dict.

Comment: I don't understand please example .How can this be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, we retrieve the record id of the saleable category from the database to create a new product:

```
import xmlrpc.client

url = 
db = 
username = 
password = 


common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})


models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'create', 
                  [{'name': 'Test Product', 'categ_id': 1}])
```

### Update:

For `One2many` and `Many2many` fields, Odoo uses a special [command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) to manipulate the relation they implement which can be used from XMLRPC:

> Via RPC, it is impossible nor to use the functions nor the command constant names. It is required to instead write the literal 3-elements tuple where the first element is the integer identifier of the command.

***Example: (create a product template with vendor pricelists)***

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'create',
                  [{'name': 'Test Product',
                    'categ_id': 1,
                    'seller_ids': [(0, 0, {'name': 1,
                                           'min_qty': 1000,
                                           'price': 258.5,
                                           'delay': 5
                                           }
                                    )]
                    }])
```

*The triplet format may change for other operations, for example for `update`, you will need to specify the record id in the following format: `(1, id, values)`*

Comment: please can you help me . how to create one2many  'order_line' and thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStation_by_id(location_ids) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var odoo = new Odoo(config_odoo);

        odoo.connect(function (err) {

            var inParams = [];
            //query 
            inParams.push([
                ['id', 'in', location_ids],
            ]);
            inParams.push(['id','name', 'subscription_community']); //  projection  fileld 

            var params = [];
            params.push(inParams);

            odoo.execute_kw('carparc.location', 'search_read', params, function (err, value) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(null);
                    throw err;
                }

                resolve(value);

            });

        });
    });

}




 var station_avaible_ = await getStation_by_id(stations_avaible)
```